# Require a specific email header field with postfix

Tags: postfix

I want to setup postfix so that email lacking a specific email header are rejected.

Is it possible to use header_check to reject emails that do not include a specific header field entry.

The solution that I believe may work is the following:

```
/^x-tituslabs-classifications-30: (<>)?$/ REJECT Classification field required
```

I want to make sure that any email going through postfix contains a `x-tituslabs-classifications-30` entry.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work. Your solution will reject all mails that **have** the header.

You can't do it with header_checks because they are only useful to check if an header exists but not if the header is lacking. That's bad but how it works.

You have to setup a mail filter (MILTER) to do that. See the documentation at http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html or alternatively http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do a pass if header, followed by a fail all?